# XAML error inconsistencies

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, namespaces

I'm trying to integrate some open source directly into my own program because I need to track down a completely unrelated bug which, without actually importing the code, I can't seem to trace back to the source.

So, I imported this code into my own program:

This is the code that works in the open source:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sparrow.Chart">
    <local:BorderThicknessToLeftAndRightConverter x:Key="borderThicknessConverterXAxis"/>
    <local:BorderThicknessToTopBottomConverter x:Key="borderthicknessConverterYAxis"/>
```

The identical code fails to work in my program after the import.  The namespaces being referenced by the clr-namespace line are identical, except my code throws all kinds of errors, saying that "BorderThicknessToTopBottomConverter (and pretty much every other item referenced by "local:" cannot be found within the referenced namespace.

Comment: Have you added `Sparrow.Chart` in your project?

Comment: If you mean added the namespace and the class in the code, then yes.  As I mentioned, I added all the c# files from the open source download into my project.

Comment: check namespace of `BorderThicknessToLeftAndRightConverter` class and other, are they in `Sparrow.Chart` namespace?

Comment: Yes. They do indeed exist within the Sparrow.Chart namespace.

Comment: It seems I've solved it - without needing to strip out any #IF statements after all.  The solution was to open the properties up and set the conditional compiler symbols to read WPF (because I'm working on a WPF application) which immediately activated the code which synchronized nicely with the XAML.

So the lesson in this is to check the conditional compiler statements and make sure that the code that is being compiled matches the conditions set forth in the conditional compiler symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sometimes encounter identical situation. What I usually do is comment all items (in your case all items referenced by the "local" namespace), rebuild the solution, uncomment all items and rebuild again. It might help you.

Comment: It's worth trying, for sure.  What's stupid in this is all the items show up in IntelliSense!

Comment: This was very helpful; and all but one of the errors were eventually cleared out.  The original software engineer included a lot of #IF directives, which were clearly designed to target various different platforms.  Stripping them out helped a lot as well.  

I've not edited the question to reflect the last error I'm getting stuck with.  It makes no sense, since 100% of everything else is working just fine.

Comment: I've marked this as the answer because it pointed me in the right direction, and helped me finally determine the ultimate solution (see comment on the original post from March 3 at 13:15)